# "name 'django' not defined" error when using the generic login view?

Tags: django, django-urls, nameerror, django-generic-views, django-login

I'm am trying to use the generic login view provided by django and this is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^login/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login),
```

When I run the server and go to

```
127.0.0.1
```

it gives me a

```
NameError at /
```

saying

```
name 'django' is not defined
```

when I remove 'django' and just leave it at

```
contrib.auth.views.login
```

it gives a

```
NameError at /
```

saying

```
name 'contrib' is not defined
```

any idea why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, try at the top of your urls.py stating: `from django.contrib.auth import views`. Then, in your url login pattern, where you originally put `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, replace it with `views.login`. If this doesn't work, please post your full urls.py.

Comment: Make sure you reinstall django before you do this as you seem to have removed it based on your description.

Comment: Ah, it worked. Looks like I just forgot to import it -.-. Thanks.